# Posted values not picked up

Tags: php

The function `constructMessageBody` is used to create the body text of an email from a contact from. The form has required and non required fields however only the its only adding the required fields to the body text of the email.

```
  function constructMessageBody () {
    $fields_req =  array("addressline1" => true, "postcode" => true, "priority" => true, "description" => true, "email" => true);
    $message_body = "";
    foreach ($fields_req as $name => $required) {
      $postedValue = $_POST[$name];
      if ($required && empty($postedValue)) {
        errorResponse("$name is empty.");
      } else {
        $message_body .= ucfirst($name) . ":  " . $postedValue . "\n";
      }
    }
    return $message_body;
  }
```

Comment: _"its only adding the required fields to the body text of the email"_, yea, it loops over `$fields_req`. You should loop over _all_ the input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add every input field of your form in `$fields_req` array. Those that are not required add them as `"field" => false`:

```
$fields_req = array("addressline1" => true, "field2" => false, "postcode" => true);
```

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thank you for your help!